# Floating StackLayout xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want in my content to have a 'StackLayout' fixed and floating where it will contain 4 'Button's.

My layout is assikm at the moment

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
       <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         Title="teste">


   <Grid>
        <ScrollView BackgroundColor="#ffffff" Padding="15" Grid.Row="0">
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="{Binding Titulo}"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#38B6AB" FontSize="22" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Data}"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#5a5a5a" FontSize="18"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>

            <Image x:Name="imagen1" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Aspect="AspectFit">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Tapped="OnTapped" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
//-----Floating button----- //
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Grid` can float things on top of other things by placing the item in the same row and column, like the following. I will note that, depending on how you place the `Button`s, it might be a usability issue to place `Button`s where the user is suppose to be scrolling.

```
<Grid>

  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> <!-- Multiple columns will allow even Button spacing, just set Grid.ColumnSpan on your ScrollView -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <ScrollView BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
              Padding="15"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            ....                
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>

  <Button Text="One"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0"/>

  <Button Text="Two"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="1"/>

  <Button Text="Three"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="2"/>

  <Button Text="Four"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="3"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: 2 errors, the buttons take all the content, there is no way to move the scrowview, the other error and the buttons are in the center, correct and appear in the footer

Comment: @José You did not specify where you wanted the `Button`s. This is just a starting point to show you how to do it. Feel free to tweak it until you have want you want. It is not meant to be a drop in solution, but is meant to help you learn how to do it. If you have trouble positioning them the way you want, let me know or post a new question,

Comment: Ok, I'm having difficulty in positioning yes, I'll open another ask